# Widget imageview bitmap error

Tags: android, widget

On emulator works perfectly, on thelephone crash ...!!
 I checked the line that crash but i can't figure why!! See the code please
 It will crash when i'm trying to update view with array of bitmap filled in the while

```
public static final ArrayList<Bitmap>  sms_rubrica = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    public static Bitmap No_Foto = null;

    public void onUpdate(Context paramContext, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, 
            int[] appWidgetIds){

        ComponentName watchWidget;
        rview = new RemoteViews( paramContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layoutmain);
        watchWidget = new ComponentName( paramContext, Randomnuberwidget.class );

        Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

        Cursor cur = paramContext.getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, "date desc limit 3");

         //Default photo

         No_Foto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(paramContext.getResources(), R.drawable.no_photo); 




       while (cur.moveToNext()) {

            String address = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address"));
            String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
            String id;
            String date;
            int idColumn = cur.getColumnIndex("_id");
            int dateColumn = cur.getColumnIndex("date");

            id = cur.getString(idColumn);
            date = cur.getString(dateColumn);


      Date dateFromSms = new Date(Long.parseLong(date));

            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(address));  
            Cursor cs= paramContext.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME},PhoneLookup.NUMBER+"='"+address+"'",null,null);

            String idContact = fetchContactIdFromPhoneNumber(address, paramContext);

            //Add photo to array 
            if (idContact.compareTo("") != 0 )  {
                  Bitmap bit= loadContactPhoto(paramContext.getContentResolver(),Long.parseLong(idContact));
                  sms_rubrica.add(bit);
              }
             else  sms_rubrica.add(No_Foto);

            if(cs.getCount()>0)
            {
             cs.moveToFirst();
             address=cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
            }

            sms_num.add(address);
            sms_body.add(body);
            sms_id.add(id);
            sms_time.add(dateFromSms.toLocaleString());


       }


        Bitmap photo = sms_rubrica.get(0);

        rview.setTextViewText(R.id.Mittente,sms_num.get(0));
        rview.setTextViewText(R.id.TestoSms,  sms_body.get(0));
        rview.setTextViewText(R.id.Orario, sms_time.get(0));
            //Here's on telephone crash giving null pointer exception but not in the emulator
        rview.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imgRubrica, photo);


      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget( watchWidget, rview );
    }
```

Here's the method to get the uri photo of the contacts

```
  public static Bitmap loadContactPhoto(ContentResolver cr, long  id) {
            Uri uri =              ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);
           InputStream input =   ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(cr, uri);

            if (input == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    }
```

Here's stack traces:

```
  02-06 01:11:44.289: E/AndroidRuntime(8624): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  02-06 01:11:44.289: E/AndroidRuntime(8624): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.imrankhanandroid.HomeWidgetRandomNum.Randomnuberwidget: java.lang.NullPointerException
   02-06 01:11:44.289: E/AndroidRuntime(8624):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1809)
    02-06 01:11:44.289: E/AndroidRuntime(8624):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
   02-06 01:11:44.289: E/AndroidRuntime(8624):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:985)
   02-06 01:11:44.289: E/AndroidRuntime(8624):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-06 01:11:44.289: E/AndroidRuntime(8624):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    02-06 01:11:44.289: E/AndroidRuntime(8624):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
      02-06 01:11:44.289: E/AndroidRuntime(8624):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-06 01:11:44.289: E/AndroidRuntime(8624):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    02-06 01:11:44.289: E/AndroidRuntime(8624):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
     02-06 01:11:44.289: E/AndroidRuntime(8624):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    02-06 01:11:44.289: E/AndroidRuntime(8624):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-06 01:11:44.289: E/AndroidRuntime(8624): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-06 01:11:44.289: E/AndroidRuntime(8624):     at android.widget.RemoteViews$ReflectionAction.writeToParcel(RemoteViews.java:730)
     02-06 01:11:44.289: E/AndroidRuntime(8624):    at android.widget.RemoteViews.writeToParcel(RemoteViews.java:1376)
     02-06 01:11:44.289: E/AndroidRuntime(8624):    at com.android.internal.appwidget.IAppWidgetService$Stub$Proxy.updateAppWidgetProvider(IAppWidgetService.java:402)
    02-06 01:11:44.289: E/AndroidRuntime(8624):     at android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(AppWidgetManager.java:283)
    02-06 01:11:44.289: E/AndroidRuntime(8624):     at com.imrankhanandroid.HomeWidgetRandomNum.Randomnuberwidget.onUpdate(Randomnuberwidget.java:167)
      02-06 01:11:44.289: E/AndroidRuntime(8624):   at android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider.onReceive(AppWidgetProvider.java:61)
    02-06 01:11:44.289: E/AndroidRuntime(8624):     at com.imrankhanandroid.HomeWidgetRandomNum.Randomnuberwidget.onReceive(Randomnuberwidget.java:205)
     02-06 01:11:44.289: E/AndroidRuntime(8624):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1798)
     02-06 01:11:44.289: E/AndroidRuntime(8624):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Attach the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the paramContext you are using for Randomnumberwidget might be what is causing the NullPointerException.

From my reading of your stacktrace, it looks like the issue is here:
Randomnuberwidget.onUpdate(Randomnuberwidget.java:167).

Try passing getApplicationContext() into the paramContext. This means that wherever the parameter is coming from that turns into the paramContext, make sure it is getApplicationContext() because sometimes if you are using a different context that changes, you can get a null pointer there.

**Edited**:

You might want to also check for null before you use the bitmaps. So in case a bitmap is a null, you use your default bitmap.

Something like this:

```
    Bitmap bit= loadContactPhoto(paramContext.getContentResolver(),Long.parseLong(idContact));
    if (idContact.compareTo("") != 0 && bit != null)  {
        sms_rubrica.add(bit);
    }
```

Comment: It's auto-gen method and the error line is marked on the code

Comment: Yes the error lines are in the stack trace. But you did not include the line numbers in your code.

Comment: where i have to pass GetApplicationContext() instead paramContext ?

Comment: check the code rview.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imgRubrica, photo);  with this instruction(it's written above) it crash and cause that exception..Without this instruction that update imageview, application doesn't crash

Comment: What's the line number of the 'rview.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imgRubrica, photo);' call?

Comment: It still crash  using paramContext.getApplicationContext() . The line is 137. It give me null pointer exception maybe because array of bitmap doesn't have good bitmap in ? I tried to load a standard  resource rview.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imgRubrica,BitmapFactory.decodeResource(paramContext.getResources(), R.drawable.no_photo)); e app didn't crash. The problem is while getting bitmap to array that make null a view